# Could not find mappable nodes or relationships inside Record

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I want to return aggregate count along with the main attributes using SDN OGM.

This is my data in Neo4j

```
{
  "identity": 777777,
  "labels": [
    "RootMarker"
  ],
  "properties": {
"lastModifiedDate": 1666934940115,
"p5Latest": true,
"messageIds": [
      "fake-900b-49ac-92c7-fake",
      "fake-fd73-4058-b07b-fake"
    ],
"messageId": "fake-fd73-4058-b07b-fake",
"deviceId": "XXXXX",
"domainId": "fake-35d5-11ed-9299-fake",
"resources": 1,
"createdDate": 1666896513598,
"drniId": 111111111111,
"isFull": true,
"resyncId": "fake-46d3-4ab1-bf34-fake",
"status": "resync",
"latest": [
      22
    ]
  }
}
```

My Repo

```
public interface StackOverFlowRepository extends Neo4jRepository<RootMarkerDTO, Long> {

    @Query("MATCH (n:RootMarker {current: true}) RETURN n.domainId as domainId, count(n.domainId) as count ORDER BY n.domainId")
    List<TestProjections> getRootMarker();
    
}
```

My main objective is return attributes as well this *count(n.domainId) as count*

Both here below works

```
@Query("MATCH (n:RootMarker {current: true}) RETURN count(n.domainId) as count ORDER BY n.domainId")
Long itWorks1();

@Query("MATCH (n:RootMarker {current: true}) RETURN n.domainId as domainId ORDER BY n.domainId")
List<RootMarkerDTO> itWorks2();
```

RootMarkerDTO:

```
@Node(labels = "RootMarker")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RootMarkerDTO{

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String domainId;
    private String resyncId;
    private String status;
    private String deviceId;
}
```

This here do NOT work

```
@Node(labels = "RootMarker")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RootMarkerDTO{

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String domainId;
    private String resyncId;
    private String status;
    private String deviceId;
    
    //Here
    private Long count;
}
```

TestProjections

```
import lombok.Value;

@Value
public class TestProjections {
    String domainId;
    Long count;
}
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.mapping.NoRootNodeMappingException: Could not find mappable nodes or relationships inside Record<{domainId: "78d89740-35d5-11ed-9299-d5f548819a2b", count: 280}> for org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.mapping.DefaultNeo4jPersistentEntity@6d2db15b
```

I missing something really important about SDN understanding. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I have created this completed replicable setup.

https://github.com/goldman7911/spring-data-understanding

MyRepository there is a method customCount() with a more realistic scenario.

```
//THAT'S NOT WORKING
@Query("match (r:RootMarker) UNWIND r.messageIds as rx return r.resyncId as resyncId, count(rx) as counter")
List<MyDTO> customCount();
```

That's is the same return from Neo4j

[image]

And the error:

> org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.mapping.NoRootNodeMappingException:
> Could not find mappable nodes or relationships inside
> Record<{resyncId: "fake-7777-4ab1-7777-fake", counter: 4}> for
> org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.mapping.DefaultNeo4jPersistentEntity@7fc420b8

EDIT2:

Following @meistermeier propose it works. I just do not understand why upper SDN layers can't handle it. What exactly is not capable of understand that.

```
public Collection<MyDTO> getRootMarkerByNeo4jClient() throws NoSuchElementException {
        Collection<MyDTO> result = neo4jClient.query("match (r:RootMarker) UNWIND r.messageIds as rx return r.resyncId as resyncId, count(rx) as counter")
                .fetchAs(MyDTO.class)
                .mappedBy((typeSystem, record) -> {
                    String resyncId = record.get("resyncId").asString();
                    Long counter = record.get("counter").asLong();
                    return new MyDTO(resyncId, counter);
                }).all();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know SDN, but that error message seems familiar. It looks like you are returning domainid and count, but the return is expected to be Neo4j.record.Record objects that contain nodes or relationships. Can you try returning the nodes that you want instead?

Comment: SDN convert Neo4j.record.Record to its appropriate type in @Node (as it does in JPA @Entity). There is only one node that I'm return one attribute and a small count of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A projection in Spring Data Neo4j always refers to an entity.
So adding e.g. the `count` to it, will create a bunch of arbitrary properties.

This is something that SDN does not consider matching for the type of the repository or its projections.
For this cases I recommend to use the `Neo4jClient` with the custom query and create the instance of the (non-)projection yourself.

```java
neo4jClient.query("<your query>")
    .fetchAs(TestProjections.class)
    .mappedBy((typeSystem, record) -> {
        Long domainId = record.get("domainId").asLong();
        Long count = record.get("count").asLong();
        return new TestProjections(domainId, count);
    });
```

Comment: I apreciate your time with this help. I have edited my issue with a replicable code in github. Check my edit bellow please. I liked this neo4jClient as well.

Comment: I commited now using neo4jClient. It got correctly mapped as you said

What I do not understand well is how the upper abstractions from SDN can't handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small update: I have opened a issue that was accepted and have milestones: 6.1.12 (2021.0.12), 6.3.7 (2021.2.7)

So, just use neo4jClient as stated by meistermeier or wait new lenient way from Spring Data.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/2633